# Outlook 2010 auto BCC with exceptions

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I've inherited an office network. 
My goal is to send all (incoming and outgoing) emails for `mydomain.com` to an external address `some_email@external_domain.com`

Scenario:
Mail server for `mydomain.com` is hosted outside (No exchange server). Clients use Outlook 2010 to POP and send emails.

-Each email address has a forward to `some_email@external_domain.com` on server-side

-Each Outlook 2010 client has been configured with:

```
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next
' #### USER OPTIONS ####
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address 
' or resolvable to a name in the address book
strBcc = "some_email@external_domain.com"
Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
    strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
             "Do you want to send the message?"
    res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
            "Could Not Resolve Bcc")
    If res = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```

Now everything works fine....except when user sends an email from `mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`. Naturally, `some_email@external_domain.com` gets two emails (from auto BCC and a server-side forward)

My question: Is it possible to exclude `*@mydomain.com` from auto BCC?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I've achieved this with following:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next

If Item.To Like "*@mydomain.com" Or Item.CC Like "*@mydomain.com" Then
'Do nothing
Else
    strBcc = "some_email@external_domain.com"
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
        "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End If

Set objRecip = Nothing

End Sub
```

This will auto BCC all email except if "To" or "CC" contains "@mydomain.com". So far works fine with my tests.

This is my first time tinkering with VBA, would be grateful to see any comments/suggestions.